# Difficulty formatting questions

Tags: support, formatting

Why is formatting on this site so incredibly difficult to figure out? Sometimes when I follow the instructions things format like I expect, and sometimes they don't (I just edited my own comment 4 times trying to format it as code. The first time I added 4 spaces to the start of every line. Didn't work. So then I tried ` before and after. Nada. So then I tried 4 spaces again. Nope. Tried ` for the 2nd time, and for some unknown reason, it worked that time.)

Just by trial and error I've discovered that a lot of the instructions for formatting are incomplete. For example, indenting by 4 spaces only creates a code block IF you have a blank line before the start of the code block. Adding a space after the last # in a heading will make the last # visible. Are there more complete (and easier to follow) formatting instructions hidden somewhere?

Comment: Can you confirm whitch help pages you used: 1:
 [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ; 2: [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) maybe other sources you found not to be helpful. That will help in fixing what is confusing.

Comment: Also, the format used is a standard format called Markdown; it is used much more widely than just on Stack Overflow. You'll find guides all over the place.

Comment: I mostly use the formatting instructions that are at the top of the question box. When something doesn't work the way that I expect, I go to the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) page.

Comment: Just by trial and error that's the way it works.

Comment: *Tried ` for the 2nd time, and for some unknown reason, it worked that time.* - You probably had a space before the backtick, like this: `. There can't be spaces between the backtick and your text if you want it to actually format your text instead of show up in comments. The four spaces thing can't work in comments because you can't have separate lines in comments.

Comment: Can you add more content to make this constructive? What documentation did you use? Do you have examples for the problems you encountered? Do you have a concrete suggestion? Do you think it is a documentation problem or another problem? (I suppose it was downvoted because it is vague and more of a rant then a concrete suggestion or question)

Answer (score 2):

> Are there more complete (and easier to follow) formatting instructions hidden somewhere?

I do not think it would be useful to have more "complete formatting instructions" than we have now.

The formatting guide is not supposed to be a formal grammar or something. It's not supposed to provide specification-levels of detail. Doing that requires makes the thing unreadable. And if you want to see how unreadable that can be, [look at the CommonMark specification](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.27/).

I'm not saying that these details shouldn't exist. I'm saying that we don't really need them *here*. The level of detail you're talking about is appropriate for a specification, not a quick reference guide.

Most people don't need to be told to put a blank line between a paragraph of text and their source code. Most people don't need to be told not to put random spaces at the end of their headers. So why should the guide bother with such trivial details?

Brevity has a value all its own. Coupled with the fact that we have an instant preview system, we just don't need such details.